# Sequelize model insert with array datatypes (postgresql)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, sequelize.js

Hi can anyone help me how to create sequelize model that can be inserted with array datatypes. My scenario is that I have 2 models (`product` & `order`), and what I want to do is that in order model I have `order_item` which will be array of `product_id` and refers to `product` table, so that I can get the rest of needed attributes.

**Note: I planned to use with raw queries

Here is my code:

**Model Product**

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../config");

const Product = sequelize.define(
 "products",
{
    id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
},
    p_image: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false,
},
    p_name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
},
    p_desc: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false,
},
    p_prize: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
},
    p_size: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
 },
{
  freezeTable: true,
 }
  );
  module.exports = Product;
```

**Model Order**

```
const { DataTypes, Deferrable } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../config");
const Product = require("./model_product");

const Order = sequelize.define("orders", {
     id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    o_items: {
        type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.UUID),
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: Product,
          key: "id",
          deferrable: Deferrable.INITIALLY_IMMEDIATE,
        },
    },
    o_quantity: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    o_total_price: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    });
module.exports = Order;
```

I planned to make the insert query like below:

```
  const sql = `INSERT INTO orders (id, o_items, o_quantity, o_total_price, "createdAt", "updatedAt")
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, now(), now())
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING *;`;
```

When I start server `npm start` I received `cannot be implemented`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "orders" ("id" UUID NOT NULL , "o_items" UUID[] NOT NULL REFERENCES "products" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE, "o_quantity" INTEGER NOT NULL, "o_total_price" INTEGER NOT NULL, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id")); 
foreign key constraint "orders_o_items_fkey" cannot be implemented
```

**EDIT**

I checked and seemed its not possible to store array of foreign key, so I changed my model to `m:n` relations between `product` & `order` through `order_items` like below:
[image]

But still my question is how to insert array of products, let say ex: user in one order he can order 3 different products. Sorry if this question is stupid, but I'm new to this and anyone please help for this matter and also I wanted to do it with query because thats the requirement for the project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See add(), $create()
Something like so

```
const order = await this.orderModel.create(createOrderDto, options)
const orderItems = await order.$add('product', [productId1, productId2, productId3])
```

I think it work not only with id but with loaded entities

```
 const product1 = Product.findOne(1)
 const product2 = Product.findOne(2)
 const orderProduct = await order.$add('product', [product1, product2])
```

And to add new image to product for example

```
product!.$create('productsImage', image)),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create many-to-may association between `product` and `order`

```
Product.belongsToMany(Order, {
  through: OrderItem,
  foreignKey: "product_id",
});
Order.belongsToMany(Product, {
  through: OrderItem,
  foreignKey: "order_id",
});
```

Then you can create an order with multiple products

```
const order = await Order.create(
  {
    id: "<uuid>",
    product: [
      { id: "pid1", order_items: { quantity: 2, price: 100 } }
    ],
  },
  { include: Product }
);
```

Then if you want to add products to an existing order

```
const order = await Order.findOne({ where: { id: "<uiid>" } });
await order.addProduct([
  { id: "pid2", order_items: { quantity: 2, price: 150 } },
  { id: "pid-3", order_items: { quantity: 1, price: 250 } },
]);
```